# How can I use CMake to link vtk library to multiple source file?

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

Here is a typical Cmakelist file with only one source file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(test)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(test MACOSX_BUNDLE test)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(test ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(test vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

The above example is if I have test.cxx and CMakeLists.txt only. What do I do if I also have a test2.cxx source file (random class) and another test3.cxx source file? I want to keep test.cxx as my main, and the other as random classes, still using the vtk library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_executable` can be used to choose source files to use for this project.

```
add_executable(test MACOSX_BUNDLE test.cxx test2.cxx test42.cxx)
```

same as

```
SET(CXX_SRC_FILES test.cxx test2.cxx test42.cxx)
add_executable(test MACOSX_BUNDLE ${CXX_SRC_FILES})
```